# Binding native iOS Swift library

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, maui, xamarin.ios-binding

I have .NET MAUI app where I want to use 3rd party payment processing library RevenueCat. There are 2 Xamarin bindings already for this lib:

- android: https://github.com/thisisthekap/Xamarin.RevenueCat.Android
- iOS: https://github.com/thisisthekap/Xamarin.RevenueCat.iOS

The Android one when referenced to .NET MAUI project works correctly, but the iOS one seems not to be supported by MAUI.

So I have decided to port it from original `iOS Binding library (Xamarin)` to `iOS binding library` on .NET7.

- I have copied all binding-related files as well as native `.framework` folder to the MAUI
- I have adjusted attributes that werent supported by MAUI e.g. `Watch`, `Mac`, `iOS` or `AutoGeneratedName`  -> [commit](https://github.com/Kebechet/Maui.RevenueCat.iOS/commit/5796f045bf6d8c591f8c5bc2afbb9535abd97bda)
- I have added necessary things to `.csproj`

and I was able to build it on my connected MAC M1 mini (from Windows).

---

But the output Nuget package was only a few KBs and the original nuget was [~7MB](https://github.com/thisisthekap/Xamarin.RevenueCat.iOS/releases/tag/release-bindings-v4.9.0.2). After closer look I found out that my MAUI nuget doesnt contain the native `.framework` resource and I have no idea why.

Do you know what am I missing?

Here is link to the repo of this nuget:
https://github.com/Kebechet/Maui.RevenueCat.iOS

Comment: Try setting NoBindingEmbedding=false in csproj: https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant/issues/1052

Comment: @o_w Thnx for recommendation, but it didnt help 

Comment: If you leave the nuget aside, and just build in Release, does the dll generated include the content?

Comment: Actually never mind, I think your problem is your project's dependency of Xamarin.iOS.SwiftRuntimeSupport. I checked it out at: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/blob/main/iOS/SwiftRuntimeSupport/source/SwiftRuntimeSupport.csproj  And it seems its target framework is Xamarin so it won't work here in Maui

Comment: No, this wasnt the problem. I tried to build this directly from MAC and it seems to be correctly built with final binary not having 31KB but 7MB. So it seems to be Windows env. problem (even though I was doing the build remotely on MAC).

Comment: If you build remotely make sure the xcode installed on the remote mac is of a version that supports your target ios framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was `.NET7` with `VS v17.7`. With that combination it wasn't possible to release binding package with embedded native library from Windows.

Workaround for that was to build it in `VS for MAC` on my MAC mini.